# CBM Program Studio Assembler syntax

Tags: assembly, 6502, c64, 6510

I'm trying to learn CBM Program Studio. But I can't get macros work for me. Withouth the macro the codes was ok. But when I add the macro part it gives "No Matching End Definition" on line 7.

Any idea?

```
        *=$c000 ; sys 49152

        ; set screen colors to black 
        lda #$00
        sta $d020
        sta $d021

defm    waitmacro ;akumulatörü hacılıyor   
        TYA
mloop   DEY
        BNE mloop
        TAY     
        endm waitmacro

        ;color bars
        LDX #$FF
loop    LDY #$07
        STY $d020

        waitmacro

        INY
        STY $d020

        waitmacro

        DEX
        BNE loop
        RTS
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work fine if you don't specify a name for `endm`. I.e.:

```
defm waitmacro ;akumulatörü hacılıyor
        TYA
mloop   DEY
        BNE mloop
        TAY     
        endm
```

I'm not sure why this is the case or why the documentation suggests otherwise.